# How to Redirect All the External Links to My Home Page

Tags: jquery, html, http

I'm working on this, and couldn't able to find the solution. I wasted my too much time in searching the solution, but still no fruit result.
I want to redirect all the external links to my home page, only external, not internal, for sure. After wasted too much time I just make this, but its not working for me.

```
$('a[href^="http://www.kownleg.com"]').attr('rel','nofollow');
```

And what should I have to do if in future (after stopping all external links), I need to put external links.

---

### Improving My Question with detail

I mean, my website Link is www.kownleg.com, I want to redirect all the Links like, if in the future I share www.facebook.com link on my website, like below, then when somebody link on the link it will be redirect to my Home Page, which is Kownleg.com. If I share the extended pages of my website then it will redirect to that page. Like if I share www.kownleg.com/whatever , then it will redirect to this page, b'cos its internal link. If I share facebook.com then it will redirect on my Home Page, b'cos its external link. Thats what I want.

```
<a href='Whatever External Link is' target='_blank'>Anything</a>
```

I have searching on this topic for a long time, any help or material similar to this topic is pretty much appreciable.

Comment: please include some html to better illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: how are you expecting to redirect anything from a source over which you don't have control? if you mean you want to make any external link end up at say, your homepage, then you may be able to. But your snippet will obviously only affect files which you host yourself.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing guys, I edit my question.

Comment: What are you using to host your website.  These kind of redirects are MUCH easier to do via the hosting platform (Apache / IIs)

Comment: @Hogan not yet buddy :( well em thinking to do, cos hosting makes to many things easier...

Comment: What do you intend to do for bookmarks to a page other than the homepage, or for a URL a user may enter into the browser that isn't the homepage?

Comment: @Hogan oh, now I get ur question, yeah for sure its hosted by someone.. I thought that u were asking that files or something of the hosting service. Actually its a Blog, hosted by blogger. em thinking to move it on wordpress, and put my hosting, so I have access to files, and I can upload files.

Comment: @TalhaHasan - OK, I see, you can't do this on wordpress.

Comment: @JGinSD nope buddy! actually I need to redirects all the present and future links which were shared or which will share on my Blog will automatically redirects to my home page (only external links), and internal links works as it normal work.

Comment: @Hogan any information would be appreciable, if u have any. for a long time em working on it. if u have any small info about it, it would be works for me. u know, something is better than nothing :)

Comment: @Hogan what about blogger? well I know they both are pretty much same. what platform work fine with it, btw.? can u suggest any thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to rephrase your question, you seem to be saying that you want to check all links on a page and any that are "external" - defined as *not* containing `www.kownleg.com` - will be changed so that they go to `www.kownleg.com`?

If so, that's not a very complicated thing to do, especially with jQuery (though you can do it with plain JS easily too):

```
// when the document is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    // iterate over all the anchor tags
    $("a").each(function() {
        // if the current link's href doesn't already contain 'www.kownleg.com'
        if (this.href.indexOf('www.kownleg.com') === -1) {
            // change current link to home page
            this.href = 'http://www.kownleg.com';
        }
    });
});
```

> *"if in the future I share `www.facebook.com` link on my website, like below, then when somebody link on the link it will be redirect to my Home Page"*

Well I've shown you *how* to do it, but I really don't understand *why* you'd want to. If your users see a link with text that implies it will take them to Facebook and the link actually takes them back to your homepage they're going to get annoyed and they're not going to use your site any more.

Comment: OK, sorry, I just don't understand what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "page request"? If the request is to a URL that is not part of your site how could you possibly intercept it?

Comment: @nnnnnn Cool man, its awesome... u rocks buddy... hats off
one thing more.. I need to exclude some links, like facebook.com, twitter.com and etc, should I have to add the conditions like u did?

Comment: Yes, just add more conditions. Or change from `.indexOf()` to a regex `.text()` and add all the required sites into the same regular expression.

Comment: @nnnnnn - wow I totally did not understand what Talha wanted!